# Every function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous (using definition)

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof

The standard proofs can be found here:
[Every function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347685/every-function-f-mathbbn-to-mathbbr-is-continuous)

But I want to see how this could be proved using directly the definition of continuity of real functions:

$ \forall x,y \;\forall \epsilon > 0 \; \exists \delta > 0 $ such that $ |x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

I tried $\delta$ = 1 and $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ but didn't work for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, $\delta=1$ works. For natural numbers, $|x-y|<1$ means that $x=y$ and $f(x) = f(y)$, so $|f(x)-f(y)|=0<\epsilon$.

Comment: Oh!! So obvious and perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: What if $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-y}$, for some $y \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @the_candyman it is a function $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{y\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, since it is not defined in $y$.

Comment: @lisyarus ok, got it, thanks!

Comment: @lisyarus  - $\delta = 1/2$ works too though, right? I read that we can pick delta such that $0 < \delta \leq 1$.

Comment: @TaylorRendon Yep, any $\delta$ in $(0, 1]$ works.